# Dynamic loading of jwplayer or any js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I want to load jwplayer dynamically using jquery or javascript. I want to do this because the browser on which FLASH is not installed jwplayer in not behaving as expected.

Hence I want to check first whether flash player is installed or not into the browser if yes than only I want to load jwplayer.To check flash installed or not i m using below

```
var hashFlash=((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false));
```

if hashFlash is true than only i will load jwplayer to play video/audio.

I am using below code to load jwplayer dynamically.

```
function loadjwplayer(filename) {
    var fileref=document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    alert(fileref);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

OR through jquery as below

```
$.getScript("/jwplayer/jwplayer.js");
```

After that i will add audio/video player into the we page as per requirement using below.

```
function load_jwplayer_skin( div_id, audio_file) { 
    jwplayer(div_id).setup({
                      file: audio_file,
                      flashplayer: "/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",    
                      primary: "flash",
                      width: "350", 
                      height: "25", 
                    });
}
```

and use it into html as below

```
<div id='audio_1'>......</div>
<script>
load_jwplayer_skin('audio_1','my_fev_song.mp3');
</script>
```

But I am getting below error "Uncaught Referenceerror: Jwplayer is not defined inside function load_jwplayer_skin ".

The same is working fine if I load jwplayer using ..... at head of the page.Hence it seems me that jwplayer is not available in global scope.

Please someone suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function load_jwplayer_skin(div_id, audio_file) {
  if(!jwplayer) {
    if(!load_jwplayer_skin.oldCalls) {
      load_jwplayer_skin.oldCalls = [];
    }
    return load_jwplayer_skin.oldCalls.push({divId: div_id, file: audio_file});
  }
  else {

    load_jwplayer_skin.oldCalls.push({divId: div_id, file: audio_file});

    var oldCalls = load_jwplayer_skin.oldCalls,
    oldCallsLen = oldCalls.length,
    i = 0;

    for(i; i < oldCallsLen; i++) {
      var oldCall = oldCalls[i];
      doLoadJWPlayerSkin(oldCall.divId, oldCall.file);
    }

    delete load_jwplayer_skin.oldCalls;

    load_jwplayer_skin = doLoadJWPlayerSkin;
  }
}

function doLoadJWPlayerSkin(divId, audioFile) {
  jwplayer(divId).setup({
    file : audioFile,
    flashplayer : "/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
    primary : "flash",
    width : "350",
    height : "25",
  });
}
```

It works like this, if `jwplayer` is not ready, the arguments were pushed in to an array.
Once `jwplayer` is ready, it loops through all the items in the array & calls the original loader `doLoadJWPlayerSkin`. And finally, `load_jwplayer_skin = doLoadJWPlayerSkin;` ensures that, future calls to `load_jwplayer_skin` are directed to `doLoadJWPlayerSkin`.

That's it.

---

### Update:

When browser starts to read a html file, it starts to render the html contents. 
If it encounters a script block, it immediately executes it(This is where, your issue spawns). If it encounters a script with `src` attribute, browser tells to some other component(you have to research it) to load the script & continues to load the rest of the page.

I guess with that details, you would understand what goes wrong where & why.

I will try to explain it here.

- In your html you add code to load `jwplayer`, lets assume that, the code is in `head` block.
- Browser informs to some other component to load the script & continues with its html parsing job.
- Now it encounters a script block & it executes the script(because, it is the nature of browser)
- That script block utilizes `jwplayer`.
- Assume, that `jwplayer` is not loaded yet.
- So, you got the error that, `jwplayer` is `undefined`.

With my approach(Actually, something like that is widely used in different forms)

- If `jwplayer` is not loaded yet, the code just stores the `arguments` in an array.
- You have many script blocks which calls `load_jwplayer_skin` function.
- So, down the timeline, when `jwplayer` is ready & from some other script block you call `load_jwplayer_skin`, that time, `load_jwplayer_skin` calls `doLoadJWPlayerSkin` with each of the previous arguments stored in the array.
- Finally it assigns `doLoadJWPlayerSkin` to `load_jwplayer_skin`. So, future calls to `load_jwplayer_skin` will directly execute `doLoadJWPlayerSkin`. Actually this is some form of `lazy initialization`.

There is one problem with my approach; that is -

Assume you started to load `jwplayer` & all the `load_jwplayer_skin` function calls are executed before `jwplayer` loads. Now nothing will happen.

For this kind of scenario, I use `events` personally. But you could just do like this,
use `jQuery` to load the script & in the callback of `.getScript` call `load_jwplayer_skin` once. In other places just call `load_jwplayer_skin`. Try this out, I am sure that your problem will be solved. If you want anything to be clarified, I here.

Good Luck!

Comment: I can not use this because i need to add multiple audio skins on a page.In that case jwplayer will be downloaded everytime(if browser support no caching).Hence i want to load js in global scope so that from anywhere withing the file i could use jwplayer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could not understand where you are going to load jwplayer.js.If jwplayer is available in global scope, I can directly  invoke doLoadJWPlayerSkin to get the skin of jwplayer at required location. My problem is to load jwplayer.js into global scope so that I can invoke doLoadJWPlayerSkin. Again jwplayer.js should be loaded only when flash player is installed. But your code is not going to deal with this. Your code seems to bind video/audio at dynamically to jwplayer. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I forgot to mention that, you could use any one of the approach that you have used to load `jwplayer`. I thought that you will figure it out. 

No problem. The reason, i called `doLoadJWPlayerSkin` from `load_jwplayer_skin` is, we don't know when `jwplayer` is ready. Browsers parse html in different way & load scripts in a different way. Please see my update in the answer for more details.